# Retrieving of Data with different JSON formats

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `jQuery` and `javascript` in an `ASP.NET` Code

Below are the 2 functions that retrieve data in different formats

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: URL,
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        try {
            window["DataList"] = eval(data);
        }
        catch (e) {
            window["DataList"] = [];
        }
        if (typeof (DataList) === "undefined" || !jQuery.isArray(DataList) || DataList.length === 0 || !DataList[0].id) {
            jQuery("#" + divnomatch).text("No Matches Found.");
            jQuery("#" + divnomatch).css("visibility", "visible");
            jQuery("#" + divnomatch).css("display", "inline");
            jQuery("#" + hdnid).val("");
            jQuery("#" + hdnname).val("");
            response([]);
        }
        else {
            debugger;
            jQuery("#" + divnomatch).css("visibility", "hidden");
            jQuery("#" + divnomatch).css("display", "none");
            fnShowHideObjTR("trResultsForRAUsers", false);

            response(jQuery.map(DataList, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.value,
                    value: item.value,
                    ID: item.id,
                    lNo: item.lNo,
                    eMail: item.eMail,
                    phyBUID: item.phyBUID
                }
            }));
        }
    }   
});
```

For this, the data comes as below...

[image: Array of Data]

Below is the function that retrieves data in different format

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: URL,
success: function (data) {
    switch (data) {
        case 'NoMatch':
            jQuery("#" + divnomatch).text("No User's last name starts with '" + searchtext + "'.");
            jQuery("#" + divnomatch).css("visibility", "visible");
            jQuery("#" + divnomatch).css("display", "inline");
            jQuery("#" + hdnid).val("");
            jQuery("#" + hdnname).val("");
            break;
        case data.charAt(0) == "|":
            lblErrorMessage.innerHTML = "Error occurred while retrieving the data: " + data.substring(1);
            fnShowHideSpan("spanError", true);
            break;
        case data.charAt(0) == "<":
            lblErrorMessage.innerHTML = "The server has not responded promptly to your \"Search as you Type\" queries. Please try again after a few minutes.";
            fnShowHideObj("spanError", true);
            break;
        default:
            debugger;
            jQuery("#" + divnomatch).css("visibility", "hidden");
            jQuery("#" + divnomatch).css("display", "none");
            var rows = data.split("|");
            var jsStr = "var DataList=[";
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
                var s = rows[i].toString();
                s = s.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
                var row = s.split("~");
                jsStr += "{id:'" + row[0].toString() + "'";
                jsStr += ",value:'" + row[1].toString() + "'},";
            }
            jsStr = jsStr.slice(0, jsStr.length - 1);
            jsStr += "];";
            eval(jsStr);
            if (typeof (DataList) != 'undefined') {
                response(jQuery.map(DataList, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.value,
                        value: item.value,
                        ID: item.id
                    }
                }));
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        lblErrorMessage.innerHTML = "The server has not responded promptly to your \"Search as you Type\" queries. Please try again after a few minutes.";
        fnShowHideObj("spanError", true);
    }
});
```

Below is the data format in data variable

[image: Array 2]

The second function works properly with the data and with its unique pipe seperator. How can I modify the code for first function which contains array of items to be pulled even with comma separator in the field in the front end as below...

[image: Dropdown which does not work properly if we type comma]

Answer (score 0):

So the problem that first function doesn't work at all or it formats the response to the incorrect format?
The suspicious thing I see now is the one of the conditions in the first `if` statement. `!DataList[0].id` would evaluate to `true` in case there is and object with ID equals to 0 which is incorrect logic I assume.

Comment: Hey @Herman, This code is already there that was working. Currently the first function does not work with comma separated values. The data is intact in arrays. But when we populate data to the dropdown, it populated with comma separated values and when I type something, it pulls data with comma. After typing comma in the dropdown, the 2nd word in the populated string disappears. Hope I am clear now...

Comment: Its all about comma that needs to be considered while typing in the textbox.